# Laravel 5.6: The page has expired due to inactivity

Tags: php, wampserver, laravel-5.6

I just updated my WAMP and PHP version into newer version. My project was working before but when I tried it in the new WAMP I cannot register or Login and there's an error.

WAMP version:3.1.7
PHP version: 7.3.1

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.
```

Any idea what happened?

Comment: check your Laravel logs file

Comment: No error in Log.

Comment: You probably have some problem with your session and you get the CSRF exception, because the tokens do not match.

Answer (score -1):

I already solved it... I just match the config/Session.php and .env and make the session drivers to file..